# How does the noun cause the suffix of compound adjectives to change?

Tags: suffixes, compound-adjectives

I'm comparing the names of bird species with similar compound adjectives. In some cases, the first word of the compound adjective changes with different nouns.

Some examples:

```
Silver-throated Tanager
Silvery-throated Jay

Rose-throated Tanager
Rosy-throated Longclaw

Black-throated Bushtit
Black-throated Jay
```

Is there a rule that determines the suffix, or is this merely a naming inconsistency?

Comment: As with postage stamps, bird colors are special. My guess is that rosy and rose are different, and so are silver and silvery. The adjectives ending in y are, I would assume, less strong and solid than those without.  You might try looking up rose and rosy.

Comment: My guess is that it's just an inconsistency.

Comment: There's no rules, these things just come from happenstance.